# Adding the Observable type to TypeScript Interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to make a TypeScript interface like this:

```
declare namespace UserService {

    interface IUserService {
        // Error: "Observable" can't be found
        getUsers(): Observable<Array<UserService.IUser>>;
    }

    interface IUser {
        Id: number;
        FirstName: string;
        LastName: string;
    }
}
```

...and then use it like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class UserService implements UserService.IUserService {

    private usersUrl = 'http://localhost:12345/api/users';

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    public getUsers(): Observable<Array<UserService.IUser>> {
        return this.http.get(this.usersUrl).map(response => response.json() as Array<UserService.IUser>);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `Observable` type in the `IUserService` isn't found. If I use Promises and use `Promise` as the type then the `Promise` type is found but I want to use `Observable`.

It is possible I'm thinking about this wrong.  I will accept a solution or an alternative.

Thank you

Comment: Have you got `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` before the `declare namespace UserService {`?

Comment: @TuongLe Imports like this in an interface don't work.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just have your interface:

```
interface IUser {
    Id: number;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
}
```

and in your service you specify that it will return an Observable Array.

```
public getUsers(): Observable<IUser[]> { // will return Observable!
    return this.http.get(this.usersUrl).map(response => response.json());
}
```

This will return a Observable of `IUser` Array :)

Also then remove the `implements` from:

```
export class UserService implements UserService.IUserService {
```

to just:

```
export class UserService  {
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah.  Maybe this is the best answer although I can't seem to let go of my original intent.  I don't see why I shouldn't be able to do it.